# Android: Load facebook page in Webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview

which is the correct way to show a FB page in a webview? I don't like this ugly mobile view. I saw it somewhere with the native blue bar from fb app and Wall/Info/Photos option buttons.

Comment: I don't know how to do what you want, but I will put a warning out there... a user on Reddit built a program that was a wrapper for the Facebook mobile site (the purpose of the program was to replace the Facebook app since it's the slowest thing in the world) and he was given a DMCA takedown notice and the app was pulled from the Market.

Comment: i don't know if we mean the same thing. What i saw was like embedding the fb app inside the webview.

Comment: Sure that it was a WebView? There's the Facebook Android ADK which is by far the best solution to integrate Facebook in an App. Maybe you should have a look at it: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: Yes, it was definitely a WebView. I will try the facebook SDK, i tried to avoid it, i just need to show a group page.

Comment: btw, it's weird that despite this is so popular i did not found any nice solution around

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get a more appealing look using the facebook touch instead. Just use:

`http://touch.facebook.com/your_page_here`